# On proofs by induction

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-explanation

The traditional structure of a proof by induction goes like this:

- **basis**: we show that the statement holds for the initial natural number $n$
- **Inductive step**: We show that if the statement holds for $n$ then it holds for $n+1$.

My question is:

Would it work if we changed the order of the inductive step: We show that if the statement holds for $n+1$ $\underline{then}$ it holds for n

Comment: Then, if your initial value was $0$,  you would have proved truth for $0, -1, -2, -3, \dots$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That doesn't quite work. I think this is a misunderstanding on how induction works. 
So for regular induction as you said what we do is:

1. Prove the statement holds for some integer $k$
2. Prove that the statement holds for $n+1$ if it holds for $n$

Now this works because since the statement holds for $k$ it would then hold for $k+1$ and then since the statement holds for $k+1$ this means it holds for $k+2$ and so on and thus the statement holds for all integers $n$ such that $n \geq k$.

Now what you're suggesting is:

1. Prove the statement holds for some integer k
2. Prove the if the statement holds for $n$ if it holds for $n+1$

Now this would work a bit differently because since the statement holds for $[k-1]+1$ this means the statement then holds for $k-1$ and then we know that the statement holds for $[k-2]+1$ which means that it holds for $k-2$, and so. the outcome would be that you proved that the statement holds for all integers $n$ such that $n \leq k$.

Now notice that if you're able to prove both of the methods above then you have proved that the statement holds for all integers.